# Python - Print readable format from String containing \n and other unicodes?

Tags: python, string, format, readable

this message was originally a set and then i converted into string with str(a)

```
a = "Let\u2019s trade!\n\u00a0\n\nAn Old Friendship, A New Day!\nHere comes the old, visiting at your home.\nIt comes with a new story, about how to live the present, about how in his past he did wrong.\n\nThe new day shines andx2"
```

and for some reason when I print it

```
print(a)
```

it keeps all the \n and \u2019s and doesn't format it into a new line or \u2019 into " ' " right quotation mark.. so it just shows as this in plaintext

```
Let\u2019s trade!\n\u00a0\n\nAn Old Friendship, A New Day!\nHere comes the old, visiting at your home.\nIt comes with a new story, about how to live the present, about how in his past he did wrong.\n\nThe new day shines andx2
```

normally if i do

```
print("Let\u2019s trade!\n\u00a0\n\nAn Old Friendship, A New Day!\nHere comes the old, visiting at your home.\nIt comes with a new story, about how to live the present, about how in his past he did wrong.\n\nThe new day shines andx2")
```

it will output it as

```
Let’s trade!
 

An Old Friendship, A New Day!
Here comes the old, visiting at your home.
It comes with a new story, about how to live the present, about how in his 
past he did wrong.

The new day shines and
```

how do i fix this?

Comment: Curious, I'd expect your first code to print the way you want it to. What kind of environment are you working in? Command line, IDE, something else? Could you provide a screenshot of your output?

Comment: I wasn't able to reproduce, using `print(a)` and `a` defined as you had it runs fine on https://repl.it/languages/python3

Answer (score 1):

I think you might be converting your initial object to a `__repr__` instead of a `__str__`.

The difference looks like what you are experiencing:

```
Python 3.6.5 (default, Mar 30 2018, 06:41:53)
>>> a = "Let\u2019s trade!\n\u00a0\n\nAn Old Friendship, A New Day!\nHere comes the old, visiting at your home.\nIt comes with a new story, about how to live the present, about how in his past he did wrong.\n\nThe new day shines andx2"
>>> print(a)
Let’s trade!


An Old Friendship, A New Day!
Here comes the old, visiting at your home.
It comes with a new story, about how to live the present, about how in 
his past he did wrong.

The new day shines andx2
>>> a_repr = repr(a)
>>> a_repr
"'Let’s trade!\\n\\xa0\\n\\nAn Old Friendship, A New Day!\\nHere comes the old, visiting at your home.\\nIt comes with a new story, about how to live the present, about how in his past he did wrong.\\n\\nThe new day shines andx2'"
>>> print(a_repr)
'Let’s trade!\n\xa0\n\nAn Old Friendship, A New Day!\nHere comes the old, visiting at your home.\nIt comes with a new story, about how to live the present, about how in his past he did wrong.\n\nThe new day shines andx2'
```

I'd look into how you are getting this string, and make sure the underlying call is `str`, not `repr`.